# VLOOKUP using `*` in the Lookup

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the following set of example data in a database:

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 0 |
| *Car | 10.85 |
| Bus | 0 |
| *Bus | 21.20 |
| Van | 0 |
| Truck | 9.90 |

I am using the following Vlookup to gather "values" based on "name"

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'LookupSheet'!$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE)
```

I want my results to look like this (based on the vlookup):

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 0 |
| *Car | 10.85 |
| Bus | 0 |
| *Bus | 21.20 |
| Van | 0 |
| Truck | 9.90 |

But what I end up getting is the following (values for Car and Bus without the * where there should be none):

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 10.85 |
| *Car | 10.85 |
| Bus | 21.20 |
| *Bus | 21.20 |
| Van | 0 |
| Truck | 9.90 |

What am I doing wrong? Is there anyway I can modify the Vlookup code such that I only get values for the names with a * where there are 2 instances of the same name (one with a * and one without)?

Sorry, I am new to Excel and trying to learn!
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `*` which otherwise acts as a wildcard in the `VLOOKUP`.

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*","~*"),'LookupSheet'!$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE)
```